# Azure Portal unable to communicate with a Service Fabric cluster without TLS 1.0 enabled

Tags: azure, security, azure-service-fabric, azureportal

I have recently disabled TLS 1.0 on all the nodes within my Service Fabric cluster after a penetration test highlighted this as a risk. Unfortunately, the Azure Portal is now unable to show me the Nodes and Applications in my cluster (even though the cluster explorer shows everything is perfectly healthy).

I disabled TLS by setting "enabled" to 0 in the following registry key:

```
HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server
```

Does this mean that the communication between the Azure Service Fabric Resource provider and my cluster is limited to using TLS 1.0?

Edit: Removed reference to Triple DES Cipher after proving that it wasn't the cause the issue.

Comment: Do they show up on [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com) in the JSON of the service fabric cluster?

Comment: No, all I see is '{ "value": [] }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft have fixed this in version 6.3.176.9494 of Service Fabric.

Release notes: https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2018/08/Microsoft-Azure-Service-Fabric-Refresh-1-Release-Notes-SDK-3.2-Runtime-6.3.pdf

> ...
>   Service Fabric now supports TLS 1.2, so versions < 1.2 can now safely
>   be disabled